# Im developing a Spring Java Project and I can not find the way to load static resources

Tags: java, spring, image, resources, itext

I'm trying to use an image that I have saved in WEB-INF but I can not. I don't know why. I have tried several ways, but for some reason, I can not find the file. I have already tried Servlet Context, FileReader, and other methods, but always with unsuccessful results. I'm so tired. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: This is a description of the images I need to use]

[image: This is a description of the exception I have]

And this is the last code im using:

```
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("/WEB-INF/static/css/images/FotosDeUsuarios/FotoDeUsuario - " + unUsuario.getSsoId() + ".jpg");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String fotoDeUsuarioContenido = br.readLine();
    br.close();

    Image imgSc = Image.getInstance(fotoDeUsuarioContenido);

    imgSc.scaleAbsolute(50f, 50f);

    encabezadoCelda = new PdfPCell(imgSc);

    tabla.addCell(encabezadoCelda);
```

Comment: try this `String path = getClass().getResource("/WEB-INF/static/css/images/FotosDeUsuarios/FotoDeUsuario - " + unUsuario.getSsoId() + ".jpg").getFile();` then `FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);`

Comment: Please post code and error messages as text as much as you can, rather than screen captures.

Comment: that been said, do you really want to apply a `Reader` to a jpeg?

Comment: @Zeronex i tried it, but it didnt work. Im getting now Estado HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @mkl  im not sure, just thought it was the best option, but im free to other approaches

Comment: I can see from the picture that your static folder is not inside WEB-INF as per your code .So copy static folder inside your WEB-INF and make sure when you build your app , in your war file those files should be available. Unzip your war file and check those files are available or not inside /WEB-INF/

Comment: @Utpal416 you were right! i fix that! but incredibly it didnt work either. It seems that for some reason im failing at defining the correct location of the root directory...

Comment: @marcez2 I asked concerning your `Reader` use because in java `Reader` classes are for retrieving textual content, not binary content. Jpegs on the other hand are binary data. Thus, as soon as you will have resolved the resource loading issue, you will see that you don't properly read it.

Comment: furthermore, after fixing what Uptal416 has found out, try Zeronex' comment again.

Comment: @mkl I just need the path not the file. And I can not succeed in retrieving the path. I have already tried the tasks advised and I could not do it.

Comment: @marcez2 can you please try a simple one first i.e. `String path = getClass().getResource("/web.xml")` and see if that works, and work you way to the actual file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried  org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource

i.e.

FileReader fr = new FileReader(new ClassPathResource("/static/css/images/FotosDeUsuarios/FotoDeUsuario - " + unUsuario.getSsoId() + ".jpg").getFile())      ;

Comment: 07-Dec-2017 00:26:04.123 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-39] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/faqu] threw exception
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/static/css/images/FotosDeUsuarios/FotoDeUsuario - zzzzzzz.jpg] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
 at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187)
 at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:48)
 at

Comment: Remove the "WEB-INF" and try it again... i.e.FileReader fr = new FileReader(new ClassPathResource("/static/css/images/FotosDeUsuarios/FotoDeUsuario - " + unUsuario.getSsoId() + ".jpg").getFile()) ;